# Finding two open brackets missing two closing brackets

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I would like to have a Regex that will match any words that begin with two open brackets but do not have two matching closing brackets.  For example:

```
Good afternoon Mr. [[Insured.InsuredName]] - Your policy 
[[Insured.CurrentPolicy is out of date.
```

In this case "Insured.CurrentPolicy" would be caught.  I'm new at lookahead/lookbehinds.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: You do not need a lookaround here. Just use `\[\[([^]]*)]]` and grab Group 1 value.

Comment: Would the match consist only of the word after the opening brackets?

Comment: Well, really nice riddle to solve. It would help if you could throw some light upon what these strings you are trying to match may consist of. I suggested using letter matching patterns, but as I also noted, `\w` can be used instead of `\p{L}` letter matching pattern in case they may also contain digits and underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try this, I got some errors on Wiktor's syntax. Could be specific to a certain version of regex. This one seems to be flexible to most regex versions.

```
(\[\[\s*[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!]])
```

[Regex Example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5C%5B%5C%5B%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%5C.%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%5Cb)(%3F!%5D%5D)&i=Good%20afternoon%20Mr.%20%5B%5BInsured.InsuredName%5D%5D%20-%20Your%20policy%20%0D%0A%5B%5BInsured.CurrentPolicy%20is%20out%20of%20date.%20This%20should%20also%20work%20on%20this%20%5B%5BInsured.SomeDataHere.%20&o=im)

Answer (score 3):

You may try using

```
\[\[(?>(\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\.\p{Lu}\p{L}*)*))(?!]])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5c%5b(%3f%3e(%5cp%7bLu%7d%5cp%7bL%7d*(%3f%3a%5c.%5cp%7bLu%7d%5cp%7bL%7d*)*))(%3f!%5d%5d)&i=Good+afternoon+Mr.+%5b%5bInsured.InsuredName%5d%5d+-+Your+policy+%0d%0a%5b%5bInsured.CurrentPolicy+is+out+of+date.)

**Explanation**:

- `\[\[` - two `[` symbols
- `(?>` - start of an atomic group that will prevent backtracking into its subpatterns so that if the lookahead after it fails the match, the whole regex could return no match
- `(\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\.\p{Lu}\p{L}*)*)` - Group 1 capturing

  - `\p{Lu}\p{L}*` - an uppercase letter followed with 0+ any letters (**NOTE**: replace `\p{L}*` with `\w*` to match alphanumeric and underscore characters)
  - `(?:\.\p{Lu}\p{L}*)*` - zero or more sequence of a dot followed with an uppercase letter followed with 0+ any letters (same note as above applies).
- `)` - end of the atomic group.
- `(?!]])` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match if there are two consecutive `]]` right after the matched text.

**In case you just need to match any non-whitespace and non-`]` characters after `[[`**, you may use [4castle's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712289/finding-two-open-brackets-missing-two-closing-brackets#comment62899021_37712379) and use

```
\[\[(?>([^]\s]+))(?!]])
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%5C%5B(%3F%3E(%5B%5E%5D%5Cs%5D%2B))(%3F!%5D%5D)&i=Good%20afternoon%20Mr.%20%5B%5BInsured.InsuredName%5D%5D%20-%20Your%20policy%20%0D%0A%5B%5BInsured.CurrentPolicy%20is%20out%20of%20date.)

Its explanation is pretty similar, just `[^]\s]+` matches 1 or more characters other than `]` and whitespace.

C# code:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(input, @"\[\[(?>(\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\.\p{Lu}\p{L}*)*))(?!]])")
       .Cast<Match>()
       .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: I think you misread the question. It's looking for opening brackets which ***don't*** have matching closing brackets.

Comment: @4castle: I have revamped the answer to address the actual issue.

Comment: That still contains a false positive in the output. You probably need an atomic group to prevent backtracking.

Comment: So, the first one should not match? The question sounds rather vague, but yes, an atomic group will be handy here. I updated the answer to reflect that requirement.

Comment: Looking good now :) For reference, [here's the PCRE regex I made](https://regex101.com/r/nE3iG5/1) which was very similar. (I'm not too familiar with the C# regex flavor, hence why I wasn't making my own answer).

Comment: I converted your regex to .NET syntax. The point is that an unachored lookbehind is redundant (in my opinion, as we can always grab Group 1 captured value) and possessive quantifiers are missing in .NET regex engine. :( It is a great pity since we can't but only use atomic groups here.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions, "not" is generally your enemy, so for this case I'd suggest just going for:

```
\[\[[a-zA-Z.]+\]?([^a-zA-Z.\]]|$)
```

It'll miss some cases like "[[Foo.Bar]Baz" but it's fairly readable and will catch a lot of cases.